# Background image stretches when trying to align nav items with logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had an issue where I was trying to align my nav items with my logo in the center someone told me to add line-height which I did and that seemed to do the trick but now the background color I have around one of my nav buttons has stretched. The image below shows my issue:
[image]

this is how my navigation looked before I added the line-height:

[image]

I would really like to get the background to look how it does in the 2nd image

here is my html:

```
   <header id="header" role="banner">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="container text-xs-center">
                        <div class="navbar-nav">
                            <a href='{{ url("/") }}' class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Our Team</a>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Media</a>
                            <a href='{{ url("/") }}' class="nav-item nav-link"><img src="./images/zipzap.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">About Us</a>
                            <a href='{{ url("/contact") }}' class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                            <a href='{{ url("/donate") }}' class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link" id="donate">Support Us</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

here is my css:

```
a.nav-item{
    color:#000;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px;
    line-height: 8em;
}

a.nav-item:hover{
    color:#000;
}


.navbar-nav{
    display:inline-block;
}

#donate{
    background-color: #7ED321;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with line-height but padding in the a.nav-item.

```
    a.nav-item{
        color:#000;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
        line-height: 8em;
    }
```

I changed the padding and it looks like something you wanted.

Check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amritanshujoshi/o0j2L6pn/